# Pegar parte do nome da classe CSS

Tags: css

Existem alguma maneira de pegar "parte do nome da classe" no CSS?

Digo isso por conta do exemplo:

```
<div class="result_itens_id1255454">
```

Vamos supor que esse `id1255454` é randômico, então não teria como eu estilizar essa div especificadamente pois sempre irá mudar (e não tenho controle sobre o backend que monta essa estrutura)

Teria como pegar parte do nome dessa classe?

Por exemplo, `div.result_itens_` pra eu poder estilizar o elemento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode até utilizar o seletor `^=` do CSS que aplicará o estilo com base no prefixo do valor naquele atributo. Por exemplo, `[class^="result_itens_"]` irá aplicar o estilo em todos os elementos que a `class` inicia com o valor `result_itens_`.

```css
[class^="result_itens_"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="result_itens_id1255454">

</div>
```

O problema é quando o elemento possui essa classe, mas não é a primeira no elemento.

```css
[class^="result_itens_"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo result_itens_id1255454">
 Não ficarei vermelho
</div>
```

Pois agora `class` inicia com `foo`, não mais com `result_itens_`. Há também o seletor `*=` que é contém um valor.

```css
[class*="result_itens_"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo result_itens_id1255454">
 
</div>

<hr>

<div class="my_result_itens_bla">
 Por que fiquei vermelho?
</div>
```

Que contorna o problema de não ser a primeira classe no elemento, mas que permite gerar falsos positivos, pois irá aplicar o estilo em todos os elementos que possuírem, de qualquer forma, o valor `result_itens_` no atributo `class`.

Comment: Um jeito - não muito bonito, mas fazer o que - é usar `[class*=" result_itens_"], [class^="result_itens_"]` (com um espaço antes de `result` no caso do `*=`), assim diminui bastante os falsos positivos (não sei se elimina 100%)

Comment: @hkotsubo Se o valor após o prefixo não importar acredito que removeria todos os falsos positivos mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, basta você usar:

```
[class^="result_itens_"]{
   propriedades aqui
}
```

O seletor `^=` irá pegar todos os elementos que possuem a classe iniciada com `result_itens_`. O sinal `^` significa início.

Irá funcionar em todos os casos onde o elemento possui **apenas** essa classe, ou, se houver a possibilidade de ter outra (ou outras), essa for a primeira da lista.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Seria classe inciada mesmo, porque se tiver `class="result_itens_123 foo"` irá aplicar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Foi isso que eu falei na resposta: "classe iniciada com `result_itens_`".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ah, entendi o que quis dizer. Troquei a palavra "uma classe" por "a classe" para não dar esse problema de interpretação. :D